# Radio-button "checked" binding doesn't add attribute to HTML element even though JS value changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

This is my code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <input name="category" type="radio" data-bind="attr: { 'value': id, 'id': 'category_'+id }, checked: $root.category.categoryId></input>
    <label data-bind="text: name, attr: { for: 'category_'+id }"></label>

    ...more inputs...
</div>
```

I **am** changing the new value to string (CoffeeScript code):

```
@viewModel.category.categoryId.subscribe (newId) =>
    @viewModel.category.categoryId(newId.toString())
```

The problem is. When I click on label one time, the `$root.category.categoryId` value does change. Subscribers fire and so on. But input element still doesn't have "checked" attribute. Only when I click on the label second or third time, it finally works and input element gains the attribute.

Also when I use jQuery `click()` on an input it works as it should, changing value and changing checked attribute.

Any idea what may be causing this behaviour?

Comment: "@viewModel.category.categoryId.subscribe (newId) =>  @viewModel.category.categoryId(newId.toString())" - it looks very strange for me: you subscribe to and change the same observable - this code does not change "categoryId" - you can simply delete this code...

Comment: This is true, I removed it, turned out newId I get is already String type. This changes nothing. I also tried to change it to Number - stack size exceeded (loop of string/number changes). Tried to trigger click() on click - well obviously, stack size exceeded (yeah this was desperate lol). I have no better idea. I am helpless and nearly crazy due to this bug.

Comment: Can you share a working sample, illustrating the issue - in jsfiddle or SO code snippet?

Comment: If I could do this, I would know what causes it, right? I can't copypaste entire app. I'm only looking for suggestions/directions.